# Unable to parse ECDSA key with Go X509 pkg

Tags: go, cryptography, ecdsa

I'm trying to parse an ECDSA secp384r1 curve key using Go's crypto/x509 package using the following code (https://play.golang.org/p/opFLBMaKhDv):

```
import (
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/pem"
    "fmt"
)

var b = `-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGkAgEBBDBsee4GAKz9Jo603xmGZ0uYEbJAoUgNqCYjDiLfj6zG4fvVSiCVxoTx
rVcvW2lmVcmgBwYFK4EEACKhZANiAATm6yBej3NVXnXAydMdLvrIB0PMr/fT6VCD
MB2pXzqxbQs8tYt3Rqd0HnzAZyYb1KhOX5lG0MyBDohhPRXqWE3gMhEq47BdzC7G
gEftttcFKXX/PSxsZUDL6GiliaB0/9E=
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----`

func main() {
    blk, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(b))
    _, err := x509.ParseECPrivateKey(blk.Bytes)
    fmt.Println((err.Error()))
}
```

but hitting the following panic

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x18 pc=0x10e9366]
```

Can someone pls tell me what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: There is no error, therefore `err.Error()` is a nil-pointer dereference.

Comment: thanks @Peter that was it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add error check.

```
func main() {
    blk, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(b))
    key, err := x509.ParseECPrivateKey(blk.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println((err.Error()))
    }

    fmt.Println(key)
}
```

Comment: Ouch, terrible API design. Now that's an NPE waiting to happen.